# Springboot Postgres slow response on server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, postgresql-11

So really not sure where to ask this.
I have a Spring Boot application running and connected to a Postgres DB. These are the machine specs:

Laptop: 8GB RAM and 8 Core CPU.
Running application out of Intellij or running as stand-alone. Application and Postgres running on same machine. Time from my logon screen into application takes less than half a second.

Server: 16GB and 8 Core CPU.
Application running inside Tomcat 8.5. I also tried running application stand-alone. Application and Postgres running on same machine. Time from my logon screen into application takes about 15 seconds.

So I have no idea why it is so much slower on the server. I can give more info if you can tell me what else to look for?

Comment: Do you use the connection pool of Tomcat?

Comment: No I am only logging into the application as a  single user. There are no other people using this application but me, so not really sure connection pooling is going to make a difference at this stage?

Comment: You could profile the application on the server e.g. using VisualVM